# Unity android weird build behaviour

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build

I am currently working on an android game in Unity. In the editor everything looks great, actor moves smoothly, generated dungeon looks nice. After building the game and start it on my smartphone the whole dungeon looks different and when moving my actor I can notice strange vibration that has never appeared before. While vibration my be caused by "wrong" implementation(I am working on very powerful Desktop so the code may be not optimal), the strange arrangement of dungeon is not about implementation at all. I tried building same version on web player and it looks jut as in editor. Look at the differences between Android-Standalone builds.
Android: http://imageshack.com/a/img901/5057/7REtUn.png
Standalone: http://imageshack.com/a/img661/2618/2Em05d.png

As you can see standalone build is just as expected, nice corridors and chambers, while on android... chaos?

EDIT: While using Unity Remote everything looks fine. Well movement isn't okay but as I said am sure now it is caused by implementation. But generated dungeon keeps unsolved.

Comment: Does this error reproduce if you don't use dungeon generation?

Comment: If the error's in your dungeon generation code, you really should include it into a question.

Comment: The generator works perfect and actually, It is pre-generated dungeon which belongs to dedicated scene. Why is that? Because I use navmeshes. And in both editor and android build I am not generating dungeon on Start but use already prepared dungeon. The whole generator I implemented I use for generating levels and then save them on each Scene.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. The "generated" adjective in your post is a bit confusing. So, the static geometry of the scene changes for some reason if you build on Android? Both the walls and the floor are static and no script modifies their position and scale?

Comment: Have you tried reproducing the bug without any scripts in the scene at all, just camera and geometry?

Comment: Well I haven't tried with only geometry and camera. Yes, both floor and the walls are static. Sorry for confusing adjective. And no, there are no scripts that could interfere into dungeon at all. After it is generated and put as a prefab, the only possibility of changing anything is generating new dungeon prefab but it would be totally independent so it doesn't make sense. I will give a try with only prefab and camera and let you know in a minute.

Comment: @_@ after leaving the level camera player and lighting everything seems to be fine. Thanks for help now it's my turn the get to know where does it make no-sense. Probably DungeonGenerator Instance which is in the hierarchy is messing around. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adjusting your targeted frame rate? Maybe your targeted frame rate is set improperly for your specific device. You may also want to try lowering the native resolution . If your resolution is really high it will cause choppiness and lag. Another item I also had to tweak to get my game to run well is the Lighting Options. From forward lighting you can change to vertex lit and it substantially speeds things up.

You may also want to mess with your shaders a bit, and see what mobile options you can go for. Various shaders have different outcomes, also rendering paths effect how things look. Are you using OpenGLS 2.0, 3.0, specifically look the settings from standalone to mobile in Player Settings.

Also make sure you're using the new Unity Remote as opposed to the old version. The old version works through wifi which is slow, the new one uses tethered USB and is relatively well.

To adjust the screen resolution as I mentioned above I had to:

75% resolution (landscape):

```
Screen.SetResolution (Screen.width * 0.75f, Screen.height * 0.75f, true);
```

To adjust target framerate as mentioned above:

```
Application.targetFrameRate = 60; //sets framerate to 60.
```